# Solve $T(n)=T(\frac{n}{a})+T(\frac{n}{b})+n^{k}$

Tags: systems-of-equations, fractional-iteration

is there known way to solve iterative equasion to direct one:

$T(n)=T(\frac{n}{a})+T(\frac{n}{b})+n^{k}$

if the starting condition like $T(n)=c$ is known

or maybe you can invent one?
thanks for answers

Comment: Any particular reason for specifying dead ones? There aren't too many of those that use the internet.

Comment: @eyeballfrog he wants Gauss or Euler to help out. I am guessing it is "Dear"

Comment: okay lol edited

Comment: Have you looked at `master theorem` Not sure if it will help - but maybe there could be some starting points

Answer (score 0):

I suppose initial condition is $T(n_1)=c$.
$$T(n)=T_0(n)+T_1(n)$$
$$T_0(n)=T_0\left(\frac{n}{a}\right)+T_0\left(\frac{n}{b}\right)+n^k, T_1(n)=T_1\left(\frac{n}{a}\right)+T_1\left(\frac{n}{b}\right)$$
$$T_0(n)=An^k \Rightarrow A=\frac{A}{a^k}+\frac{A}{b^k}+1\Rightarrow
A=\frac{a^kb^k}{a^kb^k-a^k-b^k}\Rightarrow T_0(n)=\frac{a^kb^kn^k}{a^kb^k-a^k-b^k}$$
$$T(n_1)=c\Rightarrow T_1(n_1)=c-T_0(n_1)=c-\frac{a^kb^kn_!^k}{a^kb^k-a^k-b^k}=c_1$$
I believe solution for $T_1(n)$ may be not unique. Lets try solution in form
$$T_1(n)=Bn^m \Rightarrow 1=\frac1{a^m}+\frac1{b^m}\Rightarrow m=m_1(a,b)$$
Here $m_1(a,b)$ is special function giving solution of $1=\frac1{a^m}+\frac1{b^m}$.
$$T_1(n_1)=Bn_1^{m_1(a,b)}=c_1\Rightarrow B=\frac{c_1}{n_1^{m_1(a,b)}}$$
$$T=\frac{a^kb^k}{a^kb^k-a^k-b^k}\left(n^k-n_1^k\left(\frac{n}{n_1}\right)^{m_1(a,b)}\right)+c\left(\frac{n}{n_1}\right)^{m_1(a,b)}$$